# I get the "You've entered too many arguments for this function” on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

I have a table where the user adds a chemical formula by adding elements one by one (the table has 5 rows) and i'm trying to calculate the degree of unsaturation in two ways. The user has to specify the way by writing 1 or 2 in a cell then there's this if statement:
`=IF(N16=1,((2*IF(ISBLANK(C8),0,(C8*(D8-2)))-(IF(ISBLANK(C9),0,(C9*(D9-2))-IF(ISBLANK(C11),0,(C11*(D11-2))+IF(ISBLANK(C12),0,(C12*(D12-2)))/2),(2+(IF(ISBLANK(C8),0,(C8*(D8-2))+IF(ISBLANK(C9),0,(C9*(D9-2))+IF(ISBLANK(C11),0,(C11*(D11-2))+IF(ISBLANK(C12),0,(C12*(D12-2)))))))))` 
Those ISBLANKs are for checking if there is an element written in the cell or not

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's hard to see the point of what you're doing with just this formula to look at.

**IF** it is taken as essentially your plan, with the exception of the error Excel reports, then you have the following concept in your formula:

*IF some condition (N16=1 in this case) is TRUE, then report THIS (whatever "THIS" is) and if it is not TRUE, report THIS (whatever "THIS" is) ANYWAY.*

That boils down to being the same as the following:

```
=IF(A1=1,50,50)
```

The point being that if you get the same results for TRUE and for FALSE, then there's no point in the `IF()`. Note that there can be reasons external to the logic in the situation and, who knows, one of them may apply. Since you give no information meaningful to resolving THAT, one cannot say. But if none do, and that seems very likely, why use the `IF()` at all?

So only the result of either TRUE or FALSE matters here (since they are the same). You can simplify your formula by just using one of those portions of the formula.

That's if you want to "simplify" it. If you'd rather **GREATLY simplify** it, then consider what each test does. Your basic result in each test is to subtract 2 from some cell, then multiply it by the test cell. Cool. If that test cell is blank, Excel will consider it to be 0 and that multiplication will give you 0. So why bother testing whether it is blank if the reason to do so is to make the result 0? *Just the actual multiplication will do that for you without anything else needed.* If you drop the extra work, and the whole `IF()` idea, you get the following:

```
=(2  *  C8*(D8-2)  -  C9*(D9-2)  -  C11*(D11-2)  +  C12*(D12-2)  )  /2
```

and since there seems to be no reason to multiply that by 2, then divide it by 2, take that out as well:

```
=C8*(D8-2)  -  C9*(D9-2)  -  C11*(D11-2)  +  C12*(D12-2)
```

I'll take it that the expected "C10*(D10-2)" is not there for good reasons and go onward.

Stopping the simplifying at this point (since anyway, technically speaking, anything more happens to be "streamlining" more than "simplifying" in this case), I'd point out one huge advantage to using the above and not your formula:

It's so simple, and easy to type or generate, that silly entry errors should be hard to have happen, and should be extraordinarily easy to figure out if they do. Contrast that will your formula and the advantage should be easy to see.

That, and not the particular tricks of the trade above is the important part of this answer.